# Restart celery beat and worker during Django deployment

Tags: python, django, celery

I am using `celery==4.1.0` and `django-celery-beat==1.1.0`.

I am running gunicorn + celery + rabbitmq with Django.

This is my config for creating beat and worker

```
celery -A myproject beat -l info -f /var/log/celery/celery.log --detach
celery -A myproject worker -l info -f /var/log/celery/celery.log --detach
```

During Django deployment I am doing following:

```
rm -f celerybeat.pid
rm -f celeryd.pid
celery -A myproject beat -l info -f /var/log/celery/celery.log --detach
celery -A myproject worker -l info -f /var/log/celery/celery.log --detach
service nginx restart
service gunicorn stop
sleep 1
service gunicorn start
```

I want to restart both celery beat and worker and it seems that this logic works. But I noticed that celery starts to use more and more memory during deployment and after several deployments I hit 100% memory use. I tried different server setups and it seems that it is not related.

Answer (score 2):

You are starting 2 new workers for every deployment without stopping/killing the previous workers.

During deployment, stop the existing workers with

```
kill -9 $PID
kill -9 `cat /var/run/myProcess.pid`
```

Alternatively, you can just kill all the workers with

```
pkill -9 celery
```

Now you can start workers as usual.

```
celery -A myproject beat -l info -f /var/log/celery/celery.log --detach
celery -A myproject worker -l info -f /var/log/celery/celery.log --detach
```

Comment: The advice to use `kill -9` is dubious at best. To paraphrase Randal L. Schwartz, if the process really won't die without the `-9`, it is buggy and should be removed from your system; and if you know what you are doing, you don't use `-9` unless you really have to,.

Answer (score 1):

rabbitmq may be to blame for high memory usage. Can you safely restart rabbit?

Also can you confirm that after a restart there is the expected amount of workers?